# LUKS LVM installation not booting

Tags: lvm, luks, 23.10

I can't get ubuntu 23.10 to boot in the following LUKS & LVM setup. Booting fails after entering the password and going to initramfs console.

Devices:

```
root@ubuntu:/# sudo blkid
/dev/nvme0n1: UUID="d70e1f8d-8f8a-42b9-94a9-0512edbfc70c" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="7063-2C96" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="4d7f22ab-c33c-4e37-8a06-483115a883c3"
/dev/nvme1n1p2: UUID="f3057341-06f6-4383-90cd-f2f290b9c4fc" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b897ea05-aad6-4a7b-896e-61eb44ba3ad3"
/dev/nvme1n1p3: UUID="44c313d7-64ed-457f-a960-244d266e7135" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTLABEL="root" PARTUUID="517a89d4-2e6f-42a9-b5f7-2bac9699848b"
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1_crypt: UUID="cLf6Ma-nWM5-pFmy-IUH4-mKqE-BQNj-FG2Odx" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/nvme1n1p3_crypt: UUID="uHe0yW-C6tB-Vlbk-IO4T-Uwan-VcyI-er2jfN" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/vg.expertbook-lv.root: UUID="eabd77b7-f930-4c1c-b384-56da78fb3e14" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/vg.expertbook-lv.home: UUID="c11c10c8-fe1e-435f-aa6d-4a58c734751c" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
```

2 luks-encrypted Physical Volumes:

```
root@ubuntu:/# pvs
  PV                          VG            Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/mapper/nvme0n1_crypt   vg.expertbook lvm2 a--   <1,82t    0 
  /dev/mapper/nvme1n1p3_crypt vg.expertbook lvm2 a--  474,92g    0
```

(both LUKS-container have the same password)

1 Volume Group:

```
root@ubuntu:/# vgs
  VG            #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  vg.expertbook   2   2   0 wz--n- 2,28t    0
```

2 Logical Volumes:

```
root@ubuntu:/# lvs
  LV      VG            Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv.home vg.expertbook -wi-ao----  <2,09t                                                    
  lv.root vg.expertbook -wi-ao---- 200,00g
```

In /etc/crypttab both luks-volumes are listed:

```
root@ubuntu:/# cat /etc/crypttab
nvme1n1p3_crypt UUID=44c313d7-64ed-457f-a960-244d266e7135 none luks
nvme0n1_crypt UUID=d70e1f8d-8f8a-42b9-94a9-0512edbfc70c none luks
```

I have no idea what do to, to get it working. The point is (perhaps?) the root logical volume is in a volume group which has two physical devices crypted with luks. So during boot both physical luks devices must be encrypted to read the root logical volume.

I can deliver all information - please ask. I just don't know what's important/relevant. I have really no idea what is the problem exactly.

I haven't found any tutorial with a setup like this. Another way could be to encrypt the logical volumes, not the physical volumes. But shouldn't it be go this way two?

Comment: How did you get to this point? Did you install Ubuntu 23.10 with the LVM and Full Disk Encryption options enabled? Or did you try to encrypt the boot partition after installation? Did you do something after the installation (if you installed with encryption option) that led to this situation? Did it ever boot before? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1497045/edit) and add all the information.